# c sort input by Lexicographic order without knowing the number of words in advance

Tags: c, string, sorting, input, lexicographic

i would like to solve this problem:
the user gives an input of words, separated by ', '.
i don't know how many words he would give.
the output should be: all words are sorted by a Lexicographic order.
i also need to have an access to this output for later.

example:
user input: banana, apple, soap, door (as one string, could have any number of words)
output:
apple
banana
door
soap
thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is probably not your first exercise with input. In which whay does the input method you used before fail to help you here?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What exactly is it that you have a problem with with this assignment?

Comment: how will the user supply the input? In a file, typed at a prompt, on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

Lets work on it together.  Try this for a start.  You can use it to update your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int i;

  for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    printf("word %d is %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  }
}
```

The usage and output is like so:

```
$ ./testy aword, anotherword
word 1 is aword,
word 2 is anotherword
```

Notice how the "," is part of the word?  Notice how the words are determined by the space between program args?  Think you can expand on it?

Comment: its unlikely that supplying words in the command line is what the user wants. The 'hard' parts (parsing and dynamic array allocation) are already done too.

Comment: perhaps pm100, lets try to encourage the new user (@yarden) to ask a question with code and current output.  Afterwards we can help solve their problem.  What do you say?